# Почему дом терпимости так называется?

Tags: фразеология

Есть одна версия: проститутки терпят то, что над ними вытворяют. Но а верная версия какая?

Comment: Терпимость к проявлению слабостей, страстей, пороков — ценное свойство души человеческой. Введение таких заведений властью признавалось полезным устроением. Доходным для бюджета городов, полезным для общества в части обеспечения его внешнего благочиния и сохранения, основанном на принципе терпимости, жизни женщин, оказавшихся на её обочине. Терпение же — из другой оперы.

Answer (score 1):

Это калька с французского maison de tolérance. Изначально означало, что общество толерантно относится к подобным заведениям.

> который не одобряется, но только по снисхождению терпим
>   Время выйти на поприще новое,
>   Честь имею проект предложить,
>   Все обдумано — дело готовое,
>   Стоит только устав сочинить —
>   Мысль — Центрального дома терпимости...
>   Некрасов. Современники. Герои времени.

Из словаря Михельсона 1908 г.